# Entity Framework ToListAsync() with Select()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following ActionResult in my controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> NewTickets()
{
    // Show tickets for all divisions a agent is in

    var user = "abcdefg";
    var company = "company1";

    var tickets = (from a in db2.Ticket
        join c in db2.Division on a.DivisionId equals c.DivisionId
        join dp in db2.DivisionParticipator on c.DivisionId equals dp.DivisionId
        where c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId && a.Status == "New" && dp.ApplicationUserId == user.Id
        select new
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            DivisionId = a.DivisionId,
            Name = a.Name,
            TicketDate = a.TicketDate,
            NewPosts = a.NewPosts,
            Status = a.Status,
            Type = a.Type
         })
         .ToList().Select(x => new Ticket
         {
             Id = x.Id,
             DivisionId = x.DivisionId,
             Name = x.Name,
             TicketDate = x.TicketDate,
             NewPosts = x.NewPosts,
             Status = x.Status,
             Type = x.Type
          });            

    return PartialView(tickets.ToList());
}
```

What i want to achieve is running this async, however if adding the `ToListAsync()`before `Select()`the `Select()` method becomes unavailable. The same goes for the `return PartialView(tickets.ToList())`.

I'm fairly new to working with async but reading about it's advantages I have been convering regular ActionResult methods with async ones. This has been going fine so far with easier LINQ-based queries. However for this ActionResult-method the query is a bit more advanced and the syntax/way to implement it seems to differ.

Any help to send me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ToListAsync` will return a `Task`, not a `List`, so you can't `Select` over it - you will have to `await ... .ToListAsync()` and then select over that... I do wonder why you are `ToList`ing at all at that point though.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need  `ToList` in the middle of a query? Usualy `ToList`, `ToArray` called at the end of query to save enumeration result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Split in into two statements:

```
var tickets0 = await (from ...).ToListAsync();

var tickets = tickets0.Select(...);
```

The `.ToListAsync()` returns a `Task`, so it doesn't accept the `.Select` extension method, which will need some `IEnumerable`. Only when you `await` that Task, you will get the `List`.

Another way (less readable IMO) would be:

```
 var tickets = (await (from ...).ToListAsync()).Select(...);
```

Note the extra ( ) around the await clause, which mean that the Select will work on the result of the awaited code, instead of the Task.

Comment: This, together with what @Ant P suggested it's working flawlessly! Thank you!

Comment: This might work but it will bring back every column from the table query to memory as a result of the toList and then do the projection there rather than only bringing back the projected columns.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to await the query before calling select, but given that the query is simply selecting a model out of the query you can create the model within the query and just await that.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> NewTickets()
{
    // Show tickets for all divisions a agent is in

    var user = "abcdefg";
    var company = "company1";

    var tickets = await (from a in db2.Ticket
        join c in db2.Division on a.DivisionId equals c.DivisionId
        join dp in db2.DivisionParticipator on c.DivisionId equals dp.DivisionId
        where c.CompanyId == company.CompanyId && a.Status == "New" && dp.ApplicationUserId == user.Id
        select new Ticket
        {
            Id = a.Id,
            DivisionId = a.DivisionId,
            Name = a.Name,
            TicketDate = a.TicketDate,
            NewPosts = a.NewPosts,
            Status = a.Status,
            Type = a.Type
         })
         .ToListAsync();

    return PartialView(tickets);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You also need to import `System.Data.Entity` rather than just `System.Linq`. That may seem silly, but I ended up on this question due to this. `ToList` is part of Linq but the async methods are specific to EF.